# How to make a smooth fadeIn() jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Problem** The fadeins and fadeouts are sporadic. Ideally, I would like *the fadeIn() to happen one by one; while, the fadeOut()'s all at once.  any combinations of this would be A-ok with me.*

**Background:** I've written a quick filter to hide and show through my portfolio pieces.  Along with a few animated interaction to support it.  The problem is that my interactions are a bit jarring, so I would like to add a transition between them.  The problem is that, the simple fadeIn() fadeOut() is really wonky. Heres a sample of it's wonkyness:

**[CLICK HERE LIVE DEMO](http://designobvio.us/ie/#)** (i've only applied this transition to *print navigation button*)

**UPDATE**

I've solved my problem with this script

```
$(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box').show();  
$(".box").find('.web, .video, .print').closest('.box').fadeOut('fast');
$(".box").find('.print').closest('.box').each(function(index) { 
$(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);   
});
```

**Pared down script**([script.js](http://designobvio.us/ie/asset/js/script.js))

```
    if( id == 'printInteract'){
        //used for muliple click to refresh the boxes
        $(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box').show();
       //finds the classes then filters them out
        $(".box").find('.web, .video').closest('.box').fadeOut()
           //fades in the .box(s) for print
        $(".box").find('.print').closest('.box').fadeIn();  
    }
```

**BOX HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<h1 title="Light me up"></h1>
  <div class="innerbox">
    <figure><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FtykQCyUHtg/T51fiRiRE-I/AAAAAAAADTo/mUiItl6lG0Q/s400/inspirational-animated-photography-awesome-4.gif" /></figure>
    <ul class="categorySelect">
<!-- this example has 3 tags so all buttons will show it -->        
      <li class="print"></li>
      <li class="video"></li>
      <li class="web"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end of box-->
```

**Transition trigger HTML**

```
<li id="printInteract" class="navCenter"><a id="activePrint" class="navBg" href="#"><div class="relativeCenter"><img src="asset/img/print.gif" /><h3 class="print">print</h3></div></a></li>
```

**Finally** can anyone explain why the these boxes are so random? is it load times? is it just my script hierarchy(I know my script is poorly written)  Notes on the fix would be much much appecated for I'm pretty new to jQuery script writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different take on how to do the animation.  The boxes that are being removed are animated to zero width.  The boxes that are being added are animated from zero width to their normal width.  This gives the effect of things growing into place.  All boxes are removed, then added in sequence.  You can see it work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wEZmw/

The core part of the code is a couple jquery add-on methods that let you do fades in sequence.  There are also tweaks to the CSS to help the animations look smoother.

```
jQuery.fn.fadeInSequence = function(t, fn) {
    if (typeof t == "function") {
        fn = t;
        t = 1000;
    }
    t = t || 1000;
    var pos = 0;
    var self = this;
    function fadeInNext() {
        if (pos < self.length) {
            var item = self.eq(pos++);
            if (item.is(":hidden")) {
                item.css({width: 0, overflow: "hidden"});
                item.show().animate({width: "25%"}, t, fadeInNext);
            } else {
                fadeInNext();
            }
        } else {
            if (fn) {
                fn.call(self);
            }
        }
    }
    fadeInNext();
    return(self);
}

jQuery.fn.fadeOutSequence = function(t, fn) {
    if (typeof t == "function") {
        fn = t;
        t = 1000;
    }
    t = t || 1000;
    var pos = 0;
    var self = this;
    function fadeOutNext() {
        if (pos < self.length) {
            var item = self.eq(pos++);
            if (item.is(":visible")) {
                item.css("overflow", "hidden").animate({width: "0"}, t, function() {
                    item.hide();
                    fadeOutNext();
                });
            } else {
                fadeOutNext();
            }
        } else {
            if (fn) {
                fn.call(self);
            }
        }
    }
    fadeOutNext();
    return(self);

}

function doFadeInOut(outSelector, inSelector, hideSelector) {
    var hideItems = $(hideSelector).hide();
    var outItems = $(".box").find(outSelector).closest(".box");
    var inItems = $(".box").find(inSelector).closest(".box");
    outItems.not(inItems).fadeOutSequence(function() {
        inItems.fadeInSequence(function() {
            hideItems.fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
}
```

And, here's a version where I've removed a lot of the copied code (DRY) so one common code block processes all four clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XCVy9/

Comment: this could be awesome.  It runs a bit wonky tho.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood - What does "runs a bit wonky" mean?

Comment: I really really like this idea however, seems like it can be a bit volatile.  If it could always remove correctly and append the order from left to right.  I feel its "wonkyness" would be removed.  http://designobvio.us/ie/ i've updated teh code recently if you wanna take a look.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood - yeah, that issue happens because things get made visible in the middle causing all the ones after it to jump around.  If you only add at the end, you won't see that.

Comment: how would I append them to the end? is it simple? I'm still really novice at writing jquery

Answer (score 1):

Pass a callback function and search for hidden boxes on it.

Something like this:

```
function showNextBox() {
    $('.box:hidden').first().fadeIn('slow', function(){
         showNextBox();
     });
}
$(function(){
     showNextBox();
});
```

Comment: Ah this looks interesting what triggers this function this is like a loop right?

Comment: It's recursive function, will run until there is no more hidden boxes.

Comment: yes, sorry my programming is pretty shameful. but the logic makes sense.  It's just getting my brain around it a bit more.  could you help me out a bit more?

Comment: Use $(self).find('print').fadeIn(); after the second showNextBox() call. for each print, video and web styles

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ta8ra/2/ heres the full script pared down perfectly so you can see how it works a bit better.  Logically this makes sense.  I see what you're saying but semantically I cant get it to work

Comment: of course that will show all at once, to make it sequential, follow the same basic rules.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12323/discussion-between-matthew-harwood-and-firula)

Comment: $(this).find('.print').fadeIn('slow', function(){
$(this).next().fadeIn('slow', function(){
$(this).next().fadeIn('slow', function(){
});
});
});
});

Comment: use that instead what i wrote, i wrote 'self' where it should be 'this', sorry

Comment: Hey thanks for the help I wouldnt have solved it w/o you.  My updated code is uptop if you wanna see.

Comment: Nice to know! you did it by yourself! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `show('slow')` or `fadeIn('slow')` or time in milliseconds `fadeIn(500)`

Check out the documentation for more info.to add hierarchy use function as the second argument:

```
$(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box').show("slow", function () {
    $(".box").find('.web, .video').closest('.box').fadeOut();
});
```